# script to automate copying a file?

Tags: windows, file

A client needs an updated copy of a file propagated to about 160 variations of the same folder structure on a Windows box.  can someone help me with a script to automate this?  I'm a developer, but a n00b with scripts.

the folder structure looks like:

- root

  - one

    - layouts
    - components
    - help
  - two

    - layouts
    - components
    - help
  - three

    - layouts
    - components
    - help
  - ... x 160

and I need to copy the same file to the 'components' folder.

thanks.

Comment: This could be done in powershell... some more detailed info is needed to create a script.

Comment: Voted to move to StackOverflow... It seems odd, as a 'developer' I would think you should know how to code in at least one scripting language.  Do you develop exclusively in some odd language that disallows file access? :)

Comment: I develop in C#.  I thought it'd be easier to write a script, but didn't know where to start.  maybe I'd just be better off writing a C# program to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a powershell solution I cooked up that should do what you are asking. You willneed to edit the SourceDir, Dest, and the Filter to get the file or files you want.

```
$SourceDir = "C:\Source"
$Dest = "C:\Root"
$Files = gci -Path $SourceDir -Recurse -Filter "*.txt" |?{$_.Directory -ne $null}

$Index = ($Source.Length)
$SSFile = $UpdatedPath.Substring($Index)
$Index = $SSFile.LastIndexOf("\")
$ChildDir = $SSFile.Substring(0,$Index)
$Root = Dir -Path $Dest|?{$_.Directory -eq $null}
foreach ($File in $Files){
    foreach ($Folder in $Root){
        $FolderPath = $Folder.FullName
        $DropPath = ("{0}{1}" -f$FolderPath, $ChildDir)
        Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $DropPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, just enumerate the folders on the first level and execute a copy command for each.

Pseudo code:

```
for each directory in /root

    copy file to /root/directory/components
```

Comment: "...just enumerate the folders on the first level." Perhaps abstract the function into a static method?

Answer (score 0):

Use Batch
"ROBOCOPY"

I use it to update my removable drive (USB)

Syntax:

ROBOCOPY "C:\ From Dir" "C:\To Dir" [options]
For more info,
see
http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Very good for script noobs

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a batch file - or from the command line if you reduce all %% to %

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\root" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="components" copy "d:\folder\file.txt" "%%a"
```